# 404 status returned to the request

Tags: java, http

I am trying to create a endpoint in java. I am adding the authorization as the header which is the correct one [tested and verified]. The function is as below:

```
private static HttpResponseResult response(HttpUriRequest request) {
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authHeader);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            LOGGER.info("status code is: {}", response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()); 
// here when I am printing I am getting 404.
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String responseBody = null;
            if (entity != null) {
                responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8"); 
// response body here is showing: Unable to extract parameter from http request: javax.ws.rs.PathParam("templateId")                }
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
    LOGGER.error("{}, {}", ex.getMessage(), request.getURI());
                return internalErrorResult(ex);
            }
        }
```

I am not sure why I am getting `404`. Can someone please help?

The endpoint is as follows:

```
@GET
  @Path("something/{p1}/{p2}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Timed(name = "get-requests-timed")
  @Metered(name = "get-requests-metered")
  public Response func(
          @PathParam("p1") String p1,
          @PathParam("p2") String p2) {
    Response response = functionName(p2);
    return response;
  }
```

Not really sure where is ("templateId") in the url.

Comment: 404 means not found - it doesn't have to do with auth. Bad auth would be 403 (denied)

Comment: @AzizSonawalla I updated the response body. Is there any way in which I can test?

Comment: use postman or curl to test the endpoint and see if that works.